# Calculate dB using NOVOCAINE

Tags: ios, signal-processing, core-audio, audio-recording

I want to calculate dB using [NOVOCAINE](https://github.com/alexbw/novocaine) so my question is can i measure decibels using by calculating RMS. Actually I want iphone's mic as a input and monitor surrounding noise.
I am unable to crack that. Please help.

Please give any example

Comment: dB is a logarithmic ratio of power, not amplitude so that needs to be taken into account. RMS is only amplitude.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to obtain accurate decibel leve with Cocoa?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281494/how-to-obtain-accurate-decibel-leve-with-cocoa)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, this is the math behind dB full scale:

[image: Math behind dB fullscale]

where `b` is the bit depth, on iOS `b = 16`. [More on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBFS).

This can be implemented in a way such as follows:

```
const float min = 20.0f*log10f(powf(2, 15)); // the "most silent" sample

Novocaine *audioManager = [Novocaine audioManager];
[audioManager setInputBlock:^(float *newAudio, UInt32 numSamples, UInt32 numChannels) 
{
    float f = 0.0f;
    for (int i = 0; i<numSamples; i++)
    {
          f += fabsf(newAudio[i]); // we are only interested in non-imaginary values
    }
    f /= numSamples; // kind of a poor averaging... 
    float value_dB = 20.0f*log10f(f) - min; // dB in full scale
    NSLog(@"%f dB for %f", value_dB, f); // or do whatever you want to do...
}];
[audioManager play];
```

But you should think about the sampling frequency and recall that this is dB full scale, not [dB SPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_pressure#Sound_pressure_level) or [dB SIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_intensity).

Comment: This will give you dBFS, not dB SPL which is what is desired.  There is no way to calculate dB SPL without external calibration.

Comment: You are right, but this solution is what can be done without calibration.